# Map a list as dictionary values, based on an already defined dictionary/order

Tags: python, dictionary

Take this dictionary and list for example:

```
dict = {"a": 0, "b": 0, "c": 0}
list = (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

What is the best way to map the list to each dictionary value, so that I end up with the following:

`dict = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}`

I know I can do something like this, but I'd rather have a cleaner solution:

```
i = 0
for key in dict.keys():
  dict[key] = list[i]
  i += 1
```

Comment: Just `dict(zip(mydict, mylist))`.

Comment: (1, 2, 3, 4) is a tuple not a list

Comment: Do the keys "a", "b", and "c" indicate an alphabetical order, or are those just placeholders for actual keys? If the keys have no apparent order, you will have to make the original dictionary into an OrderedDict to preserve some key order. If you're using Python 3.6+, insertion order is preserved though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dict comprehension

```
dict1 = {"a": 0, "b": 0, "c": 0}
list1 = (1, 2, 3, 4)

{k:v for k,v in zip(dict1.keys(),list1)}
```

or just

```
dict(zip(dict1.keys(),list1))
```

Answer (score 3):

Python dictionaries are not sorted a priori - you could, however, do something like this:

```
for k, key in enumerate(sorted(d.keys())):
    d[key] = l[k]
```

PS: I wouldn't call your variables `dict` and `list` as those are built-in functions.

Comment: I like the sorting idea if the key/value pairs are supposed to be based on alphabetical indexing. A condensed version could be `new_d = dict(zip(sorted(d), l))`

Comment: Python 3.7+ respects insertion order.

Answer (score 2):

Note that dictionaries are an unordered collection. This means that there is no guarantee that numbers from your list will be assigned to keys in your dictionary in the same order the keys were declared.

Regardless, a cleaner way to achieve the functionality of the code you posted is

```
for i, key in enumerate(dict.keys()):
    dict[key] = list[i]
```

**Edit**

As of python 3.7 dictionaries are guaranteed to respect insertion order.

> Changed in version 3.7: Dictionary order is guaranteed to be insertion order. This behavior was an implementation detail of CPython from 3.6.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values

Comment: Python 3.7+ respects insertion order.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the dictionary maintains order, that is not the case in all version if Python, you can construct such dictionary with:

```
dict(zip(mydict, mylist))
```

For example:

```
>>> mydict = {"a": 0, "b": 0, "c": 0}
>>> mylist = (1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> dict(zip(mydict, mylist))
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

This works since you can iterate over a dictionary, it will then emit the keys. You can use `zip(..)` to concurrently iterate over the keys of the dictionary, and the values in the tuple. Finally we use `dict(..)` to convert the iterable of two-tuples into a dictionary, where each 2-tuple is a key-value pair.

Comment: Python 3.7+ respects insertion order.

Answer (score 2):

Use enumerate to get the index and keys of your dictionary then comprehension to put them into a new dictionary.

```
mydict = {"a": 0, "b": 0, "c": 0}
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]
newdict = {k: mylist[i] for i, k in enumerate(mydict)}
newdict

{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```